# How can I replicate Spacemacs's evil bindings on the helm-find-files / helm switch to buffer modes?

Tags: key-bindings, evil, helm

I'm moving away from Spacemacs to vanilla Emacs + Evil and I liked the C-hjkl shortcuts that were available while navigating helm buffers (`C-h` / `C-l` moved up/down directories in helm find files, `C-j` and `C-k` moved up and down options). I guess the broader question may be is there a way to get evil bindings to work everywhere (not just in the above examples)? If it helps, I'm starting to use the `general` package for leader key functionality

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spacemacs bind hjkl navigation for helm manually through this [spacemacs//helm-hjkl-navigation](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/blob/532ad2567cba1d57d09e102c385315e7cfa829ec/layers/%2Bspacemacs/spacemacs-completion/funcs.el#L98), you can copy to your own configs.

As for getting evil bindings to work everywhere, I suggest to use [evil-collections](https://github.com/emacs-evil/evil-collection). Note that there are a few differences from Spacemacs.